# How to iterate JSON data in a Node Js app

Tags: node.js, json, iteration

I am facing an issue while iterating a JSON data using the .foreach in a Node Js application.
The JSON Content looks as below,

```
{
"JR":{"James$James.Albert$string":"11","John$John.Ab$string":"22"},
"US":{"Philip$Philip.Jose$string":"44","Maichel$Maichel.Kim$string":"33"}
}
```

I have used the below code set for iterating but getting error : Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

```
JSON.parse(rfcData).each((index, variable) => {
   log.info(" ############  IIIIIII ########### ",index);
    log.info(" ############  IIIIIII ########### ", variable);

});
JSON.parse(rfcData).forEach((index, variable) => {
  log.info(" ############  IIIIIII ########### ",index);
    log.info(" ############  IIIIIII ########### ", variable);

});
```

Can anyone please help and let me know were i have gone wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, there is clearly something wrong with the JSON in `rfcData`.  You can paste your exact JSON into this validator https://jsonlint.com/ or https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html.  Also, the JSON you show in your question is NOT an array (it's an object) so you can't use `.forEach()` with it and `.each()` is not a Javascript method at all.  The error you report seems to indicate that there's something different in `rfcData` than what you show in your question because that error does not match what you show here.

Comment: After you fix your JSON parsing problem, you can iterate the keys/values of an object with `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(parsedRfcData)) { console.log(\`${key}: {value}\`); }`

Comment: Please update your post with an actual example that's giving you `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.  Please look at billobeng's response [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164718/421195).  Please "upvote and/or "accept" it if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by json.parse from your example does not have a ".each" or ".forEach" method try this instead

```
const json = JSON.stringify({
  "JR":{"James$James.Albert$string":"11", "John$John.Ab$string":"22"},
  "US":{"Philip$Philip.Jose$string":"44","Maichel$Maichel.Kim$string":"33"}
})

Object.keys(JSON.parse(json)).forEach(value=>{
  log.info(value)
})
```

Using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: If the object is a JSON array it would have .forEach etc after JSON.parse

Comment: yeah true, edited my answer to reflect I am referring to the data he provided

Comment: I tried your option and able to get "JR" and "US" . How can i get the values also
{"James$James.Albert$string":"11", "John$John.Ab$string":"22"}

Comment: you can assign the JSON.parse(json) to a variable and then access the value  in the forEach function

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the JSON you're trying to iterate is not an array, so you cannot loop using `each` or `forEach` neither `map` functions. You instead need to loop through keys of the parsed `Object`.

```
Object.keys(JSON.parse(yourJSON)).map(value=>{
  log.info(value)
})
```